# LINQ equivalent of this subselect

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

"Tasks" table:

```
public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

"Task History" table:

```
public class TaskHistory
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public TaskStatus { get; set; }
}
```

**Sql query**: Which tasks were completed in the last 30 days?

```
select * from Tasks 
where TaskStatus in ('Completed', 'Rejected')
and ID in (
    select distinct TaskID 
    from TaskHistory 
    where LastModified >= DateAdd(day, -30, GETDATE())
)
```

Q: What is the equivalent LINQ expression for this SQL query?

Comment: Why don't your classes have navigation properties? **It's impossible** to propose a Linq query replacement for that SQL without seeing your **actual** EF entity types with FK relationships.

Comment: What is `TaskHistory` meant to represent when your SQL only queries the `Tasks` table? I've downvoted your question because you clearly haven't spent much time thinking about the question you're asking - which is out-of-line for someone like yourself with 10k+ karma. You should know how to ask a good question on SO by now.

Comment: I guess the SQL subquery is supposed to be from table `TaskHistory`, rather than `Task`.

Comment: 1) Typo in the subselect: should be "TaskHistory". 2) My understanding is that "navigation" implies a) extra code in the Context .cs, and b) introducing a Foreign Key constraint into the DB schema. "b)" would be a deal-breaker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do what yo want:

```cs
var statuses = new [] {"Completed", "Rejected"};

var query = 
   from t in ctx.Tasks
   where statuses.Contains(t.TaskStatus)
      && ctx.TaskHistory
         .Any(th => th.LastModified <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)
             && th.TaskID == t.ID)
   select t;
```

Comment: @FoggyDay - Do profile this answer, as it really does appear to be quite inefficient.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. The original query should be profiled too.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv - thank you again.  I'm not sure what freaked everybody out: 1) my typo ("from Task" instead of "from TaskHistory" - since corrected), 2) that I didn't include the EF context (it's minimal - only the classes were relevant), 3) that I deliberately chose *NOT* to use EF navigation or 4) something else entirely.  Anyway - your solution is great!

Comment: Their comments are correct. I just see main idea of the query and I know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I missing something, I think your query is doing this:

```
IEnumerable<Task> query =
    from t in tasks
    join th in taskHistory on t.ID equals th.TaskID into ths
    where
        ths
            .Where(x => x.LastModified < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30.0))
            .Any(x => new []
            {
                TaskStatus.Completed,
                TaskStatus.Rejected,
            }
            .Contains(x.TaskStatus)
    select t;
```

It's a weird one.